# Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section using multiple pulldown menu and new line

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am getting the following error. I looked at many stack overflow questions and most of the answer says to reloadData or delete the row. The problem happens like this. When I write something for `a`, it works. Then, I press `Other` for `b`, so a new line will appear and it would work. The same goes for the next two `g` and `i` and I would give it an input which would work. After, when I try to give `f` a value, it would give me this error below. I am very new to swiftui and I am confused about where to put it. Any advice or help will be very appreciated.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 4. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

```
struct NewBehaviorView: View {
    //@State var id = 0
    @State var a = ""
    @State var b = ""
    @State var c = ""
    @State var d = ""
    @State var e = ""
    @State var f = ""
    @State var g = ""
    @State var h = ""
    @State var i = ""
    @State var j = ""
    @State var k = ""
@State var listb = [...]
@State var listc = [...]
@State var listd = [...]
@State var liste = [...]
@State var listf = [...]
@State var listg = [...]
@State var listg = [...]
@State var listi = [...]
@State var listj = [...]
@State var listk = [...]


    @State private var isExpandeda = false
    @State private var isExpandedb = false
    @State private var isExpandedc = false
    @State private var isExpandedd = false
    @State private var isExpandede = false
    @State private var isExpandedf = false


    var body: some View {

        VStack (alignment: .center){
            Group {
                Text("").navigationBarTitle("...")
            }
            Form {

                Section(header: Text("a")){
                    TextField("Enter a", text: $a)
                }

                Section(header: Text("b")){
                    DisclosureGroup("\(b)", isExpanded: $isExpandeda){
                        ScrollView {
                            ForEach(listb, id:\.self) { list in
                                Text("\(list)")
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        self.b = list
                                        withAnimation {
                                            self.isExpandeda.toggle()
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (b == "Other") {
                        TextField("Specify", text: $c)
                    }
                }



                Section(header: Text("g")){
                    DisclosureGroup("\(g)", isExpanded: $isExpandedb){
                        ScrollView {
                            ForEach(listg, id:\.self) { list in
                                Text("\(list)")
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        self.g = list
                                        withAnimation {
                                            self.isExpandedb.toggle()
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (g == "Other") {
                        TextField("Specify", text: $h)
                    }
                }


                Section(header: Text("i")){
                    DisclosureGroup("\(i)", isExpanded: $isExpandedc){
                        ScrollView {
                            ForEach(listi, id:\.self) { list in
                                Text("\(list)")
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        self.i = list
                                        withAnimation {
                                            self.isExpandedc.toggle()
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if(i == "Other") {
                        TextField("Specify", text: $j)
                    }
                
                }

                Section(header: Text("f")){
                    DisclosureGroup("\(f)", isExpanded: $isExpandedd){
                        VStack {
                            ForEach(listf, id:\.self) { list in
                                Text("\(list)")
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        self.f = list
                                        withAnimation {
                                            self.isExpandedd.toggle()
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                Section(header: Text("d")){
                    DisclosureGroup("\(d)", isExpanded: $isExpandede){
                        VStack {
                            ForEach(listd, id:\.self) { list in
                                Text("\(list)")
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        self.d = list
                                        withAnimation {
                                            self.isExpandede.toggle()
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if(d == "Other") {
                        TextField("Specify", text: $e)
                    }
                }

                Section(header: Text("k")){
                    DisclosureGroup("\(k)", isExpanded: $isExpandedf){
                        VStack {
                            ForEach(listk, id:\.self) { list in
                                Text("\(list)")
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        self.k = list
                                        withAnimation {
                                            self.isExpandedf.toggle()
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }


                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the content of your `alllist` variable?

Comment: @cedricbahirwe It is a string array.

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.